# How to get the file info of YouTube contents?

Tags: youtube-api

I got the contents URL via YouTube share function(in android mobile phone).

How to Get to the File Info of Contents URL information only?(format, format/info, format profile).

The ultimate goal,
I want to got the Youtube content file info in Android Mobile Phone.
Below to obtain information?

For example

```
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not something that is supported via any YouTube API.

Please ensure that you're familiar with the [YouTube API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) which explains what you are and are not permitted to do with the API.